# Update / Merge table with summing values

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update

I have a schema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9917/1

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id NUMBER,
  period NUMBER,
  amount NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1000, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1000, 1, 500);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1001, 1, 200);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1001, 2, 300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1002, 1, 900);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (1002, 1, 250);
```

I want to update the amount field by adding amounts of records which has same (id, period) pair. like after op :

```
  ID|  period|   amount
1000         1      600
1001         1      200
1001         2      300
1002         1     1150
```

I Couldn't figure out how :(

EDIT:

In actual case this table is populated by insertion operation from other 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table1(
  id NUMBER,
  period NUMBER,
  amount NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO some_table1 VALUES (1000, 1, 100);
INSERT INTO some_table1 VALUES (1000, 1, 500);
INSERT INTO some_table1 VALUES (1001, 1, 200);
INSERT INTO some_table1 VALUES (1001, 2, 300);
INSERT INTO some_table1 VALUES (1002, 1, 900);
INSERT INTO some_table1 VALUES (1002, 1, 250);

CREATE TABLE some_table2(
  id NUMBER,
  period NUMBER,
  amount NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO some_table2 VALUES (1000, 1, 30);
INSERT INTO some_table2 VALUES (1000, 1, 20);
INSERT INTO some_table2 VALUES (1001, 1, 15);
INSERT INTO some_table2 VALUES (1001, 2, 20);
INSERT INTO some_table2 VALUES (1002, 1, 50);
INSERT INTO some_table2 VALUES (1002, 1, 60);
```

Dublicates occures when two insertions done:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (id,period,amount) SELECT id,period,amount from some_table1
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (id,period,amount) SELECT id,period,amount from some_table2
```

new sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd45b/1

May be it can be solved during insertion from two table..

Comment: Why didn't you define a primary key on id, period? You have now multiple records with the same id and period. There is no way you can update only one of them with sum of all of them. What you could do is to create another table into which to consolidate the sums. Then you can delete the first and insert into it all the data. But if you don't define a primary key, then you will probably get this situation over and over.

Comment: yes creating a new table solves it, but i cant do it. I didnt create the table it was designed like this :(

Comment: if there is a unique key like xid how can i do it?

Comment: A unique key on that same table? It may help, but it depends on what you actually want to obtain... you have 2 rows with id=1000 and period=1. Do you want amount=600 on one and to delete the other? Do you want amount=600 on both (doubt that)? Or what else?

Comment: I mean an extra field xid which is unique in the same situation.

Comment: We need to know what you want to do with rows with the same id and period... update one and delete the rest? or update them all?

Comment: I updated the question i think repeated rows can be avoided while insertions

Comment: I updated the answer. You can avoid duplication on insertions, in Oracle, with the MERGE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script like this would do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table_summary (
  id NUMBER,
  period NUMBER,
  amount NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO test_table_summary (id, period, amount)
SELECT id, period, SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM test_table
GROUP BY id, period;

DELETE FROM test_table;

INSERT INTO test_table (id, period, amount)
SELECT id, period, total_amount FROM test_table_summary;

DROP TABLE test_table_summary;
```

But you should actually decide if test_table is to have a primary key and the total amount or all the detail data. It's not a good solution to use one table for both.

By what you have added, then I'd say you can use the Oracle MERGE INTO statement:

```
MERGE INTO test_table t
   USING (SELECT id, period, amount FROM some_table1) s
   ON (t.id=s.id AND t.period=s.period)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.amount=t.amount+s.amount
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (t.id, t.period, t.amount)
     VALUES (s.id, s.period, s.amount);
```

Beware though... this will work only if test_table already has no duplicate id, period rows to begin with. So if your table is already messed up, you still have to reinitialize it properly a first time (and maybe add a unique id, period key to avoid problems in the future).

Comment: i cant create an extra table :(

Comment: I haven't used Oracle in a long time. Can't you create an in memory table? Something to scratch when you commit the transaction, I mean.

Comment: The problem is you cannot update the table with values read in from the same table by aggregation... you can't in SQL (but you could use a client application or a stored procedure to do it by cycling on the rows). What you can do in SQL is to use a secondary temporary table to put the aggregated results. You still haven't explained clearly what you expect to happen to the original multiple rows with the same id, period.